# oh-my-zsh: git maximum nested function level reached

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Get an error when I use standard git command:

```
[~/site]$ git branch
git:1: maximum nested function level reached
```

.zshrc:

```
plugins=(git osx colored-man gem brew go bundler rake rails)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My mistake, I moved bash function to zsh:

```
gr() {
  git rebase -i HEAD~$1
}
```

Solution:

```
function gr() {
  git rebase -i HEAD~$1
}
```

Comment: per chance are you holding FunCoin? Its literally all I have.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error with a different command (`export`), caused by an accidental recursive function definition. I could solve the problem by removing the unwanted function:

```
unset -f export
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, with a different command: `find`

### TL;DR

Don't invoke aliases to a function inside the function script.

---

### The error

```sh
$ find ~ -name some_thing
find_no_err:1: maximum nested function level reached; increase FUNCNEST?
```

### The issue

- I have created a function **f** (`find_no_err`), that use a command **c** (`find`)
- then, defined an alias that associate the command to the function, as follow

```sh
alias c=f
```

- so I ended up with a resurrection without a stop condition :

```sh
# the recursion issue
c=f(c)
```

### the solution

Avoid invoking aliases to functions or commands that call a given function inside its script

or, in the case of `c=f(c)`, don't call `c` form `f`

Instead, use one of this 3 options:

- use a relative path to the command (eg `cmd`)

```
  ./cmd
```

- use the full path to the command

```
  # to get it, in linux systems, use
  whereis cmd
```

- quote the command invocation inside the function script

```
  'cmd'
```

### in practice

I just quoted find invocation, inside the function body

```sh
find_no_err(){
  'find' $* 2>/dev/null
}
```

then sourced the file (cf. [zsh doc](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) for "source file", cf. [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_18_01) for "dot description")

### what this has to do with the original question ?

1. the issues seem similars: a git call invokes a git alias/function that invokes its invoker ...
2. omz's [git plugging](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh) , add a long list of git alias, among which there is

```sh
alias gr='git remote' # line 246
```

which may had some conflict with the OP custom function, after [git branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) call (but I don't see how)

3. In my case, the accepted solution doesn't work

adding the optional (cf. [zsh doc](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html)) `function` identifier, doesn't prevent the alias invocation within the function body (by default). that leads to the recursion issue, which throws "maximum nested function level reached;" error

4. it is possible* to share custom functions between bash and zsh, by putting them in a separate dotfile, then sourcing it from there respective rc files

---

### Alternatively

You can `unset` or remove the changes, as mentioned in **bluenote10** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46295137/16953460)

Answer (score 1):

closing the terminal and reopening it, worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `command` to stop the recursion.

In my case I had this in my `.zshrc`:

```
docker() {
  docker $*      # <-- recursive
  if [[ ..
  ...
}
```

worked just fine after changing the `docker` call to:

```
docker() {
  command docker $*
  ...
}
```