# how to add a additional completion to the already defined git subcommand completion?

Tags: git, autocomplete, zsh, zsh-completion

I was experimenting with custom git subcommand completion:

I am trying to extend the completion for `git commit -m` or `git commit --message`.

$HOME/.zsh/completions/_git-foo   (this path is added to fpath fpath+=~/.zsh/completions)

```
#compdef git-foo

_git-foo() {
  _git-commit

  local -a commands
  commands=(
    'hello-git:our first autocompletion function.'
    'version:show the used gem version.'
  )

  if (( CURRENT == 3 )); then
    if [[ $words[2] == "--message" || $words[2] == "--message=" || $words[2] == "-m" ]]; then
      _describe -t commands 'commands' commands
    fi
  fi

  return 0
}

_git-foo
```

but the main objective is to add this additional completion to the already defined `_git-commit` completion without breaking the original completion function for `git commit`

I have tried to change the `#compdef` directive to `#compdef git-commit` and file name from `_git-foo` to `_git-commit` but it didn't work.

I was getting the following error:

```
_git-commit:1: maximum nested function level reached; increase FUNCNEST?
_git-commit:1: maximum nested function level reached; increase FUNCNEST?
_git-commit:1: maximum nested function level reached; increase FUNCNEST?
```

Creating your custom completion for a custom subcommand works fine, but how to extend the already defined git completions without breaking the original one?

Answer (score 1):

Note that I'm not yet able to acheive what you're aiming to do. I am also fiddling with zsh custom autocompletion lately, hopefully what I found can help you out

In any case I'll be interested in your feedback as I'm discovering the ropes as well :D

## Maximum nested function level error

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70336970/10707406) from user [4015-alt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16953460/4015-alt):

You are attempting to define a function `_git_commit` which calls itself, thus creating a recursion. To prevent such mistakes from creating infinite loop, zsh will stop when the amount of nested function call reaches configured amount: FUNCNEST

## Potential solution

Based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/501111) from user [Attila](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/337296/attila)

You could save a reference to the original `_git_commit` completion function used natively by git, and redefine it as you need
Then use the reference you saved to call back the original completion function:

```
_git_commit_orig="$functions[_git_commit]"

_git_commit() {
  [...]
  _git_commit_orig "$@"
}
```

As mentioned by Attila:

> You wouldn't need to call compdef again, since it is already bound to that function, and you just changed the function definition.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi @Bleacks. I actually had problem with recursion as well. I ended up not going this route. I'll take a look at it and give it a try. I think it is good know how to extend the functionality of existing completion function for future works. Thanks